# Can't add parameters to the Signature base string GET call on new Twitter API

Tags: java, matlab, twitter

I cannot complete a GET call to the new Twitter API when I add parameters to the Signature base string (`'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com'`). My code, written using Matlab with `java.io.included`, fails at the point that I make a java call: `BufferedReader`.

Things are fine if I do not add any Request query (parameters) to the Signature base string. The string I send looks exactly as it should when I compare it to the results provided by Twitter's handy OAuth testing tool: 
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/4145370/oauth

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is URL encoding required in your scenario?

Comment: You may want to post the code you have, if possible.

Comment: Thanks Juned. Sorry for not including it:

Comment: httpMethod = 'GET';
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json';
%% The wrapped java
import java.net.URL java.net.URLConnection java.io.*;
import java.security.* javax.crypto.*
import java.io.BufferedReader

% Define the percent encoding function:
percentEncode = @(str) strrep( char( java.net.URLEncoder.encode(str,'UTF-8') ),'+','%20');

%httpMethod = upper(httpMethod);

theURL = URL(url)
% Open http connection:
httpConn = theURL.openConnection;
httpConn.setRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

% Set authorization property if required:

Comment: % Set authorization property if required:
% define oauth parameters:
signMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1';
params.oauth_consumer_key = twtr.credentials.ConsumerKey;
params.oauth_nonce = strrep([num2str(now) num2str(rand)], '.', '');
params.oauth_signature_method = signMethod;
params.oauth_timestamp = int2str((java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis)/1000);
params.oauth_token = twtr.credentials.AccessToken;
params.oauth_version = '1.0';
params = orderfields(params);
%%
% Compose oauth parameters string:
oauth_paramStr = '';
parKey = fieldnames(params);

for ii=1:length(parKey)

Comment: for ii=1:length(parKey)
    parVal = percentEncode( params.(parKey{ii}) );
    oauth_paramStr = [oauth_paramStr parKey{ii} '=' parVal '&'];
end
oauth_paramStr(end) = []; % remove the last ampersand.
% Create the signature base string and signature key:
signStr = [ upper(httpMethod) '&' percentEncode(url) '&'...
    percentEncode(oauth_paramStr) ];
signKey = [twtr.credentials.ConsumerSecret '&'...
    twtr.credentials.AccessTokenSecret];

Comment: %%
% Calculate the signature by the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm:
import javax.crypto.spec.* % key spec methods
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.* % base64 codec
algorithm = strrep(signMethod,'-','');
key = SecretKeySpec(int8(signKey), algorithm);
mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
mac.init(key);
mac.update( int8(signStr) );
temp = char( Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal)' );

Comment: params.oauth_signature = temp;
%params.oauth_signature = char( Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal)' );
disp([params.oauth_signature ' ' temp])
params = orderfields(params);
%%
% Build the HTTP header string:
 httpAuthStr = 'OAuth ';
% this section finds all the oauth parameters 
parKey = fieldnames(params);
ix_mask = ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(parKey,'oauth'));
ix = find(ix_mask');

Comment: for ii=ix
    httpAuthStr = [ httpAuthStr ...
        percentEncode(parKey{ii}) '="'...
        percentEncode(params.(parKey{ii})) '", '];
end
httpAuthStr(end-1:end) = []; % remove the last comma-space.

% Set the http connection's Authorization property:
httpConn.setRequestProperty('Authorization', httpAuthStr);

%% Handle POST
% if POST request:
if strcmpi(httpMethod,'POST')

%%
% get the response:
inStream = BufferedReader( InputStreamReader( httpConn.getInputStream ) );
%%

Comment: Java exception occurred:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
 at
        sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
         at
        sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)

Comment: Can you compare your code to my MATLAB file exchange app at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20290-update-twitter-status? It supports only updating status. It works once you update the URL to use 1.1 API.